# How to remove this Django APP ID type error

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to install requirements for a Django project of My teammates after cloning it. but it is not working and I can't also make migrations. whenever I try running migrations I'm getting this error

```
 (name, text, type(obj)))
TypeError: app_id should be a string instead it is a <class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: How does your `settings.py` look like?

Comment: show the entire error trace. And how are you installing the requirements? What is not working?

Comment: after posting this question I have been looking for a way to solve it and I have finally found that I have made a typo in ```.env ``` file while setting push id variable and I'm sorry for asking such a small question